# Hive create new table having complex types from an existing table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Given an Hive table

```
create table movie_1(id int, movie_title string, actor string, gender string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'  

vi movies.txt 
1;hero;john penn;male 
2;hero;maggie mcguirre;female 
3;lost;peter jones;male
```

Assuming a new table `movie_2` but with fields of type `STRUCT`:

```
create table movie_2(id int, movie_title string, STRUCT <actor:string, gender:string>)
```

How to create  a new table `movie_2` from existing table `movie_1` i.e. select from `movies_1` insert into new table movies_2 ?

Answer (score -1):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403396/how-to-load-hive-table-with-mapstructs-from-another-flat-simple-hive-table). You can use to_map UDF in this case for creating new table with complex datatype.